# My "Avast: Mobile" security is giving me massive warnings about Trojans such as: "Android:SMSSend-DC[trj]"

Tags: malware, antivirus

I got these warnings on my Samsung phone by the "Avast: Mobile" Security application about having malware (mostly trojans). So I scanned my phone and Avast said that i had over 50 applications infected with at least 20 malwares each. Is this a malware of some sort that hit all my applications? Or just hit Avast?

I downloaded Malwarebytes mobile app to search for the viruses, and found nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: same here, seems an obvious avast problem. Let's see what they come up with. I'm on cyanogenmod 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalled, then reinstalled Avast. Scans now all clear.

Looks like a definite Avast issue.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of users reporting about these Trojan warnings.

**It may be Avast Virus Defenition Update issue.**

**Post From Avast Moderator**
[image: Moderator Post]

**Update the VPS to 14010901**
[image: Update to latest]

[**Source Forum**](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=131641.0)

[image: bug screen]
From [Google+](https://plus.google.com/111443407622333064492/posts/BBNzseYQzQK) found this image. I think its a similar issue.

Comment: Note that after upgrading your virus definitions to 14010901 you may still have a "Malware found" warning until you re-scan all of your apps with these updated definitions: http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=144421.msg1047406#msg1047406

Answer (score 2):

From the latest reviews on the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.mobilesecurity) it appears as though others are experiencing the same issue this morning. I expect there is a problem with the latest definition update which is causing a lot of apps to be detected as a virus/malware.

The only advice I can give is wait for them to release a new update which resolves the issue. If there is a report issue feature within the app you could try using this, or the email address on the Play Store to ensure they are aware of the problem.